# Branch manager wants to transfer me to a lower position against my will, what is the best way to handle it?

Tags: work-environment, job-change, work-life-balance, tanzania

I work in the bank designated as teller. It's been 15 month since I started and for a very long time my communication with our branch manager is not cool. He is the boss that does not listens and always takes things his way. The main cause for this is me being part of a soccer team of our company; we are playing a second division league in our country aiming to reach for premier league level. He does not like it at all. He pushes me to work extra hours just so I don't attend training. I work 8/5 but he pushes us to be working 8/8, we have to categories of which the ones working 8/8 has a 3 to 4 days off a weak while us (8/5 shift) only rest on Sunday. The branch is among the best branch in the company, also the football team has become a big symbol inside and outside the country. It lead me to be no good neither in football nor in bank operations, as everyday I have to fight with my boss in order to leave. Leaving on time here is something legal that looks like illegal when you do it. I am not comfortable anymore with my working condition and I feel so weak around him as I can say nothing that he listens to; instead he provokes. No peace anymore. I don't know how to deal with this, what he is doing does not build me, and the other position he wants to shift me is like a punishment. It will also bring no good for my development and personal self as well. The company is huge with 29 branches in the country of which 16 are in the city where I live; also there are lots of departments I can fit in. I wish to leave the branch but I don't know how.

(Copied from comment by OP to a deleted answer): And it is not something I can just quit; the company CEO is the one responsible for the existence of the soccer team as part of marketing and branding. The other branch lives nicely in their work environment; it's just us under his branch. He provokes everyone here, but he is really good in business and numbers; leadership tools are poor. I am the one getting extra trouble because of football. We all get trouble with him but mine is extraordinary. The CEO won't let me back off from football and he doesn't know all about this.

Comment: In which country is this?

Comment: Tanzania (east africa)

Comment: I have no idea what is happening here other than your not happy and soccer. Can you please split this into an background section about the reasons and the actual question? Otherwise, this just seems like a meaningless rant.

Answer (score 9):

Just summarising from comments to a delete answer:

1. This is all about you being in a football team and your branch manager apparently hating football and making your life hard because of it.
2. However, the football team is the creation of the company CEO. So the company CEO wants the team to succeed.
3. Your branch manager tries hard to make you fail both in your professional life and as a football player.

The thing to do is to contact the CEO without your branch manager knowing about it, and telling him that your branch manager makes you work extra hours to keep you from playing football. Put it forward politely: "I a very sorry that I won't be able to participate in the football team anymore, because my branch manager insists that I leave at eight instead of leaving at five so that I cannot participate in football training. Maybe I could change to this other branch, where everybody leaves at five".

What the branch manager does - if I understand the situation correctly - is what you call a "career limiting move". The CEO may not care about you or about you being told to do overtime, but he cares about the football team, so your branch manager will have some explaining to do.